# how can I suppress OMP warnings #96 Cannot form a team

Tags: openmp

I have a pipeline that processes 1000 images. Each image goes through a 4 step process to create input for a model. So there are 4000 data preparation tasks plus a final prediction task. Total 4001 tasks.

The 4000 data preparation tasks are parallelised by luigi so 4 tasks run at once on 4 cpus. For this I set OMP_THREAD_LIMIT=1 otherwise it hangs due to a conflict between luigi and OMP.

The final prediction task uses pytorch. This is a single luigi task but is parallelised by pytorch via OMP. So I reset OMP_THREAD_LIMIT before starting the task.

This works but during the first 4000 tasks I get hundreds/thousands of warning messages....."OMP: Warning #96 Cannot form a team with 4 threads using 1 instead" and "OMP: Hint consider unsetting......OMP_THREAD_LIMIT".

How do I disable these messages? Or is there some other way to temporarily disable OMP without OMP_THREAD_LIMIT?

Comment: You need to describe your workflow and the involved components better. It is totally unclear what you mean by "temporary" and "step".

Comment: Have rewritten to be clearer hopefully.

Comment: You need to say more about your environment. Which compiler are you using? These messages are from the OpenMP runtime, which is compiler dependent, so any solution is also very likely compiler dependent...

Comment: I did not compile openmp. Actually I did not install it explicitly but probably it was installed as a dependency of some other package. I can see intelopenmp in my conda list. Is there no way to suppress the messages at runtime as I would prefer not to have to compile it. I am running in a linux docker container with anaconda and a long list of installed packages. openmp probably came with luigi or tesseract.